# Can I use NAS to access database on a network?

Tags: nas

I want to ask if I can use NAS to store the main database like for example Firebird or MySQL and access this database from network ? if so how to install the database server software ?

Comment: NAS is only **storage**. It can't run your DBMS server software. Do you not understand what Network Accessible Storage means?

Comment: The word **STORAGE** is important. It means **STORAGE**, not **SERVER**.

Comment: nowadays, a NAS (like from Synology) is a full fledged computer running Linux. So, of course, it can also act as a SERVER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!
What's your nas model?

For example in my Synology i can enable web server and install mysql + phpmyadmin just in few clicks.
I just need to access in the admin panel and using the PacketManager start installing the software.

I'm sure it's possible to do the same with Qnap.

Comment: if possible tell the steps to install MySQL in your model

Comment: That's technically not a NAS. That's a server that they are calling a NAS.

Comment: follow this guide: https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Application/How_to_manage_MySQL_databases_on_your_Synology_NAS_with_phpMyAdmin#t1

Comment: Is there a way to install Firebird as well ?

Comment: @Chris Fannin Yes I know. Technically it's a mini server. It's not just a NAS but nowadays many people have adopted this term to give a name to these mini servers. When I speak about NAS with other people all they think these mini servers.

Comment: @Wel I don't know sorry. I never tried. I have done a rapid google search and I can say if it's possible it's not easy like mysql. You need access your NAS using ssh and install it bypassing the Admin Panel.

Answer (score 1):

A "NAS" is simply Network Attached Storage. A personal example is the [Western Digital My Cloud](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=1140). You can use it to host the data files themselves, but no software can be installed.

There are networked solutions that are basically mini servers. They have slimmed down versions of a Linux build that run web servers, database servers and the like. I do not have any examples to provide since I do not have the need for one, but I know they are out there from prior research.

To learn about what a NAS is, you can check out the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage).

Answer (score 1):

NAS is basically just storage, it doesn't really run a useful OS. You need a server to host MySQL or similar DB. You can install MySQL on a Windows, Mac or Linux OS, the DB file(s) would reside on those machines and the MySQL services would respond to API requests appropriately. Here are some links to installing MySQL:

Windows - [http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-mysql-for-php-applications-on-iis-7-and-above](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

Linux - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu